# Android application stopped working-Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an Android application that will solve some math functions according to the code. But when I save it, then run on emulator and when the emulator is launched it says me The application has stopped working.

Java Code;

```
package com.example.fibonacci;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btn1;
TextView tv1;
EditText edt1;
String msj= "d";

double n = Double.valueOf(edt1 . getText().toString());

double a = (1 / (Math.sqrt(5))); 
double b = ((1+(Math.sqrt(5)))/2); 
double c = ((1-(Math.sqrt(5)))/2); 
double i = a * ((Math.pow(b,n)) - (Math.pow(c,n)));
String k = String.valueOf(i);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    edt1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Click kodu buraya yazılacak

            msj = edt1.getText().toString();
            tv1.setText( k );
        }
    });   
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.fibonacci.MainActivity" >


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="number to cal."
    android:inputType="number" >


</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:text="result" />
```

Comment: Can you post stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double n = Double.valueOf(edt1 . getText().toString());
```

is outside of a method which means it runs before `onCreate()` which means your `EditText` is `null`. That can't be run until you initialize your `EditText` (i.e. must be after `edt1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);`)

You are going to run into problems then with those calculations trying to run before `onCreate()`. Put them in a method and call them when you need to.

In the future, please provide the logcat with your post when your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the n with the edit text's value, but your edit text object is null yet.

```
double n = Double.valueOf(edt1 . getText().toString());
```

Initialize after

```
edt1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
```